# Background of chrome manifest 2 json not working

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, manifest

I'm doing a chrome app to show twitter search widget. My app works fine with manifest version 1 and using "backgroud_page" I can show my apps main html page well and its working well but with manifest ver 2's new background is not working for me.

```
"description": "Live",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 1,
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "index.html"
    }
  },
  "background_page":"index.html",

  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  }
```

above is working well but the below is not working well

```
  "description": "Live",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "index.html"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "pages": "index.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  }
```

With manifest 2, page loads but the java scripts is not loaded. but  manifest 1 works fine.

can u please help me.. how to load that javascript using manifest 2...

please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the background element, it should be 'page', not 'pages'.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html